# How can I fix or ignore the warning "Also define the standard property 'appearance' for compatibility"

Tags: css, visual-studio-code

I am using tailwind css, and vs code shows the follwoing warning:

> **Also define the standard property 'appearance' for compatibility.**

How to fix it or ignore it

```css
button,[type="button"],[type="reset"],[type="submit"] {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just... do what it tells you: Add the `appearance` property, and set its value to the **same value** as whatever you set the non-standard vendor-prefixed property to. Ex:

```
button,[type="button"],[type="reset"],[type="submit"] {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  appearance: button; /* <-- add this */
}
```

See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/appearance.

If you want to disable this warning in VS Code, then put the following in a [settings.json file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson):

```json
"css.lint.vendorPrefix": "ignore",
```

Note that there is also a related `css.lint.compatibleVendorPrefixes` setting that you may or may not be interested in. Its default value is already `"ignore"`.