# Fix warning "Also define the standard property 'appearance' for compatibility" on normalize.css

Tags: html, css, sass, normalize-css

I am really new to css and web building in general and I wanted to use a normalize.css file but I get an error in two lines of code.

```
button,
   [type="button"],
   [type="reset"],
   [type="submit"] {
     -webkit-appearance: button;
   }
```

and

```
[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration {
     -webkit-appearance: none;
   }
```

I know that the error is asking me to define appearance as plain as it could be, but I don't know how to do this and I don't want to mess up the normalize file in trying to do so. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

For reference I am using the normalize.css file from https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

I searched up the warning and tried to apply similar solutions but to no avail.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fix warning "Also define the standard property 'appearance' for compatibility"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76156404/fix-warning-also-define-the-standard-property-appearance-for-compatibility)

Answer (score 0):

this means also add standard style rule while added -webkit styles

```
[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration {
     -webkit-appearance: none;
     appearance: none;
}
```

this should work.