# Also define the standard property 'appearance' for compatibilitycss(vendorPrefix)

Tags: css

I'm really new to this thing and I'm trying to follow a yt tutorial for codeigniter4.(This is the link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rsAlrtGllcA&list=PLRheCL1cXHruubPUc9c934IjUP5NYnDBX&index=3)

But when I go https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css. I copy the css contents inside then paste it inside the Public/asset/css folder i get this error:

Also define the standard property 'appearance' for compatibilitycss(vendorPrefix)

Property is nonstandard. Avoid using it.

Changes the appearance of buttons and other controls to resemble native controls.

(Chrome, Safari 3)

Syntax: none | button | button-bevel | caret | checkbox | default-button | inner-spin-button | listbox | listitem | media-controls-background | media-controls-fullscreen-background | media-current-time-display | media-enter-fullscreen-button | media-exit-fullscreen-button | media-fullscreen-button | media-mute-button | media-overlay-play-button | media-play-button | media-seek-back-button | media-seek-forward-button | media-slider | media-sliderthumb | media-time-remaining-display | media-toggle-closed-captions-button | media-volume-slider | media-volume-slider-container | media-volume-sliderthumb | menulist | menulist-button | menulist-text | menulist-textfield | meter | progress-bar | progress-bar-value | push-button | radio | searchfield | searchfield-cancel-button | searchfield-decoration | searchfield-results-button | searchfield-results-decoration | slider-horizontal | slider-vertical | sliderthumb-horizontal | sliderthumb-vertical | square-button | textarea | textfield | -apple-pay-button

### No quick fixes available

The error I get is specifically on the -webkit-appearance:

I expect that there will be no errors since I'm following every step he did on the video and I'm using all the latest versions of the softwares needed

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fix warning "Also define the standard property 'appearance' for compatibility"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76156404/fix-warning-also-define-the-standard-property-appearance-for-compatibility)

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar error related to numeric input, and what helped me was to change from -moz-appearance to appearance.
Take a look at this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/appearance